# What to add in CIDR-ADDRESS in pg_hba to accept from all IP

Tags: postgresql, ip

I want an IP address or regex which allows to accept all IP addresses in CIDR-ADDRESS in pg_hba.conf . I tried 0.0.0.0/0, but says

```
ERROR: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Answer (score 0):

That suggests your server isn't running.  0.0.0.0/0 is correct, so the error must be elsewhere.

Generally speaking:

1. Start postgresql
2. Try again
3. If fails, check your postgresql log to see why it is not running
4. If nothing and postgresql is running, then check iptables, and other networking aspects.